# python replace space with special characters between strings

Tags: python

I would like to replace all spaces between strings with '#' except for the space after the end of string.

Example:

```
input=' hello  world    '
output = '#hello##world'
```

I know using `rstrip()` I can neglect the space at the end of string . I just want to try without using `rstrip()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```
import re
a = ' hello  world    '
a = re.sub(' +$', '', a)
output = re.sub(' ', '#', a)
```

but really, this is better:

```
output = re.sub(' ', '#', a.rstrip())
```

Comment: You don't need `re.sub()` in the last example: `s.rstrip(" ").replace(" ", "#")`. To replace any whitespace: `re.sub(r"\s", "#", s.rstrip())`