# Replacing special patterns in a string, reading from a file

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to replace special patterns in string by tabs. This string ( if i may call it) is a result from reading a file, that has accents (I'm portuguese, so UTF-8 or LATIN-1 is the encoding language). 
So imagine my input is:

```
Aubrecht, Christoph; Özceylan, Aubrecht Dilek; Klerx, Joachim; Freire, Sérgio (2013) “Future-oriented activities as a concept for improved disaster risk management. Disaster Advances”, 6(12), 1-10. (IF = 2.272) E-ISSN 2278-4543. REVISTA INDEXADA NO WEB OF SCIENCE 

Aubrecht, Christoph; Özceylan, Dilek; Steinnocher, Klaus; Freire, Sérgio (2013), “Multi-level geospatial modeling of human exposure patterns and vulnerability indicators”. Natural Hazards, 68:147-163. (IF = 1.639).. ISSN: 0921-030X (print version). ISSN: 1573-0840 (electronic version. Accession Number: WOS:000322724000008
```

Some of those special patterns are :

```
') "'    --> '\t'
'), "'   --> '\t'
'),"'    --> '\t'
') "'    --> '\t'
'),«'    --> '\t'
'), «'   --> '\t'
') "'    --> '\t'
```

Until now I've tried using a dictionary to replace all those characters, but happens that the dictionary doesn't recognize some of those patterns. I know the re.sub function is the "man" for this ([python replace space with special characters between strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324998/python-replace-space-with-special-characters-between-strings)) but that's cool when you have a predifined string, but when you read from a file, how do you do it?

My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import Tkinter as tk
import codecs, string, sys, re

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Final?")

f = open('INPUT TEXT', 'r')
with codecs.open('INPUT TEXT', encoding='latin1') as f:
    sentence = f.read()
    if isinstance(sentence, unicode):
     sentence = sentence.encode('latin1')


def results1():
 print '\n', sentence

print results1, '\n'

key = {0:') "', 1:'replace'}
regx = re.compile('\t\t{[0]}\t\t'.format(key))
print( regx.sub(key[1],results1) )




def replace_all(text, dic):
 for i, j in dic.iteritems():
    text = text.replace(i,j)
 return text

reps = {' (':'\t', ') "':'\t', '), "':'\t', '),"':'\t', ') "':'\t', '),«':'\t', '), «':'\t', ') "':'\t', 'p.':'\t', ',':' '}
converts = replace_all(sentence, reps)

def converts():
 sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'w')
 converts = replace_all(sentence, reps)
 print '\n', converts



 results = tk.Button(root, text='Resultados', width=25, command=resultadosnormais)
 results.pack()
 txt = tk.Button(root, text='Conversor resultados', width=25, command=conversortexto)
 txt.pack()

 root.mainloop()
```

I saw this post too but I can't seem to apply it on my code in specific :[Re.sub not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033375/re-sub-not-working-for-me)

But somehow it stores the function at somewhere but it gives a error right after that:

```
File "C:\Users\Joao\Desktop\Tryout2.py", line 30, in <module>
regx = re.compile('\t\t{[0]}\t\t'.format(key))
error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

Comment: Your **replacement patterns** are predefined, so a regex is just the ticket.

Comment: why are you using the key?

Comment: @MartijnPieters What do you mean?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I thought that was one of the ways to work with re.sub or re.compile

Comment: @dbpyth: *that's cool when you have a predifined string, but when you read from a file, how do you do it?* It doesn't matter where your strings come from (from a file or elsewhere), because your `re.sub()` pattern is pre-defined, hardcoded. You are not reading the pattern from the file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So if I can't read the pattern from the file, how do I do to recognize those specials and convert those into \t?

Comment: About your specific error: you need to escape parenthesis `)` with backslash `\ ` in pattern, like this: `key = {0:'\) "', 1:'replace'}`

Comment: @pavel_form That gives an error:`TypeError: expected string or buffer `

Comment: @dbpyth , can you post a traceback?

Comment: @pavel_form `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joao\Desktop\Tryout2.py", line 31, in <module>
    print( regx.sub(key[1],results1) )
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: Oh, looks like I read code without attention last time. That is because results1 is not a string, but function object (from this line: `def results1():`). You need to pass actual string to re.sub call, I'm assuming it is `sentence`. `print( regx.sub(key[1],sentence) )`.

Comment: Wow pavel_form, that actually worked! Thanks you so much

Comment: If you mean you want to use re.sub for replacement and not method replace_all with reps dict, then yes, yes.

Comment: @pavel_form I did tried to apply this to all and i did this: `key4 = {0:'\),«', 1:'replace'}
regx4 = re.compile('\t\t{[0]}\t\t'.format(key4))
print ( regx.sub(key[1],sentence) )

key5 = {0:'\), «', 1:'replace'}
regx5 = re.compile('\t\t{[0]}\t\t'.format(key5))
print ( regx.sub(key[1],sentence) )
` But somehow the last two patterns dont convert ( the input i tried was this : `qualquercoise) "dffdf
qualquercoise), "dffdf
qualquercoise),"dffdf
qualquercoise) "dffdf
qualquercoise),«dffdf
qualquercoise), «dffdf `

Comment: That might be lack of attention in copypasting :) . You have `key4` (`key5`)and `regx4` (`regx5`) but you're using `key` and `regx` in sub.

Comment: Yeah that was a huge fail :D Thanks for pointing that out